# Lyx: runninghead always right

Tags: latex, lyx

I create a running heading with the command "runninghead"
Now the running head is on every other side on the left side.

I wanna print the work onesidedly so I want to get the running heading on every page on the ride side.

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better-suited on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com).